# HttpURLConnection vs Volley or Retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, httprequest

I have recently started learning about how to make an HTTP request, in the course I took, i was taught creating HttpURLConnection object to create request, while in some tutorials i saw people using Volley or Retrofit as libraries. Could someone help me know the difference between them if any?, else what are they exactly?

Comment: Hi @Pulkit, Stack Overflow isn't really meant for software recommendations. If you were working on an implementation using some other library and were encountering an error, you could ask about that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit is more extensible as it has all kinds of converters, makes the request to the network and can parse the response from your logic. It is also compatible with Kotlin and JavaRx coroutines. It is based on OkHttp for the connection and has a very large community to consult in case of doubts.

https://github.com/square/retrofit